# How to filter array of objects from key value pair in properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

If I have some data in this structure:

```
const topFilms = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994, cast: [{'Al Pacino': false}, {'Morgan Freeman': true}] },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972, cast: [{'Marlon Brando': true}, {'Al Pacino': true}] },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974, cast: [{'Al Pacino': true}, {'Robert De Niro': true}] },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 }
];
```

How can I create a new array of items that have a specific key value pair in their properties? For example, I'd like an array of films that star Al Pacino, so I need to filter the array to include objects that have the key value pair `'Al Pacino': true` in their properties. **This code does not work** - it's just my best attempt.

```
const alPacinoFilms = topFilms.filter(function (film) {
  if(film.cast){
    return film.cast.includes({'Al Pacino': true});
  }
});
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/m-use/pen/ZEEjVOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you can't compare objects with `===`, because they're different objects.
- Secondly, you want `some` instead of `includes` when you have something other than comparing for exact equality.
- Lastly, consider having your cast fields just arrays of strings instead of objects with true/false values.

```js
const topFilms = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994, cast: [{'Al Pacino': false}, {'Morgan Freeman': true}] },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972, cast: [{'Marlon Brando': true}, {'Al Pacino': true}] },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974, cast: [{'Al Pacino': true}, {'Robert De Niro': true}] },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 }
];

let alPacinoFilms = topFilms.filter(film => film.cast && film.cast.some(castMember => castMember['Al Pacino']));

console.log(alPacinoFilms);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't filter Objects like that. You need to iterate over the array in some way to check it, not pass in an Object to get a match. You can test if one element at least matches using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const alPacinoFilms = topFilms.filter(function (film) {
  if(film.cast){
    return film.cast.some(function(obj) { return obj['Al Pacino'] });
  }
});
```